Build Tailwind Style into index.html with Angular
I'm working on an Angular project with tailwind inline style, currently when I build the project, it will create a styles.css file and add the link to the index file <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'">.
I already enable the inlineCriticalCss in project.json but it doesn't include all the tailwind style in .html files.
I'm looking for a way to include all tailwind style from .[html|ts|css] or how can I just tell Angular not to link to css file and just copy the style to index file
